# RECOGER NUMERO DE FORMULARIO CON $_POST

Tags: php, html, formularios, post

No me deja recoger el numero del formulario con el metodo post y no se donde podria fallar. Es un programilla para transformar numero a letras de la siguiente manera (15935= "uno cinco nueve tres cinco")A ver si me podeis ayudar un poco que ya lo he probado casi todo.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="Practica1.php" method="post">
    <br/>
    Introduzca Numeros: <input type="text" name "numeroElegido" value=""><br/>
    Enviar <input type="submit" value "Enviar" />
    </form>
    <?php
    $numeroElegido =$_POST["numeroElegido"];
    function numerosAletras($numero){
$numero = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
$letras = ["cero ","uno ","dos ", "tres ", "cuatro ","cinco ","seis ","siete ","ocho ","nueve "];
return str_replace($numero, $letras, $numero);
}
echo numerosAletras("numeroElegido"); 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un par de problemas en este código.
Al pulsar el botón de enviar los datos del formulario se envían al script que pones en action. Este script puede ser otra página o la misma en la que está el formulario, en este caso tienes que diferenciar entre la llamada a la página directamente vez o desde el formulario. No se como lo estás haciendo, pero me parece que usas esta segunda forma.
Luego el script para convertir letras en números no puede funcionar de ninguna manera. Hay que cambiarlo.
Vamos por partes. Crea la página pagina1.php  (ojo que uso minúsculas en los nombres de archivos). En esta página pones el código para determinar si se ha pulsado el botón enviar, si es así ejecuta la función php y si no pues sigue mostrando HTML.

```
<?
  if (!isset($_POST['enviar'])){
?>  
    <form action="practica1.php" method="post">
    <br/>
    Introduzca Numeros: <input type="text" name="numeroElegido" value=""><br/>
    Enviar <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="enviar"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
    else{
      $numeroElegido =$_POST["numeroElegido"];
      function numerosAletras($numero){
          $letras = ["cero ","uno ","dos ", "tres ", "cuatro ","cinco ","seis ","siete ","ocho ","nueve "];
          $cadena = "";
          for($i = 0; $i < strlen($numero); $i++){
              $cadena .= $letras[$numero[(int)$i]];
          }
          return $cadena;
        }
      echo numerosAletras($numeroElegido); 
    }
    ?>
```

Si quieres verlo en funcionamiento lo [tienes aquí](https://creatuweb.espaciolatino.com/sols/practica1.php) Verás también el código fuente con el php correspondiente. Hay más formas de hacerlo, esta es la más simple.

Answer (score 0):

Un par de cosas a comentar:

La primera es que tienes errores de sintaxis en tu html, las etiquetas `name` y `value`, tienen que ir acompañadas por un `=`

Luego en tu php, no compruebas si el `$_POST["numeroElegido"]` ha sido inicializado, por lo que te salta un error. Tampoco imprimes el valor del mismo.

```
<body>
    <form action="prueba2.php" method="post">
        <br />
        Introduzca Numeros: <input type="text" name="numeroElegido" value=""><br />
        Enviar <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["numeroElegido"])) {
        echo  $_POST["numeroElegido"];
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

En cuanto a tu función, tienes unas cuantas cosas mal:

-No le pasas correctamente el valor a la función.

-En la función estas sobreescribiendo el numero que recibes

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST["numeroElegido"])) {
        $numeroElegido =  $_POST["numeroElegido"];
    }

    function numerosAletras($numeroRecibido)
    {
        $numero = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
        $letras = ["cero ", "uno ", "dos ", "tres ", "cuatro ", "cinco ", "seis ", "siete ", "ocho ", "nueve "];
        return (str_replace($numero, $letras, $numeroRecibido));
    }
    echo numerosAletras($numeroElegido);
    ?>
```